# UISwitch won't show up in custom UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiswitch

I made a custom UIView class and trying to set up in it an UISwitch controller programmatically. The UISwitch won't show up. Where's the evil?

UIView class:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    uiSwitch=[[[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.00,200.00,79,27)] autorelease];
    [uiSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(uiSwitchCurrentStatus) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self addSubview:uiSwitch];
}
```

I've checked another issues regarding UIswitch, but all of them seems like not my case. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>(if inside UIViewCotroller)</sub> Try `[self.view addSubview:uiSwitch];`

Or if this really inside the UIView class, move the whole method to a view controller.

Or put the the code in `UIView`'s `layoutSubviews`.

And in any case you should check, if the switch already exists. Otherwise it could be leaking.

Also <sub>if placed in view controller</sub>`- (void)viewDidLoad` might be the better place.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    if (!uiSwitch){
        uiSwitch=[[[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.00,200.00,79,27)] autorelease];
        [uiSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(uiSwitchCurrentStatus) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self addSubview:uiSwitch];
    }

}
```

Comment: My class is @interface DrawItemDetails : UIView. It doesn't contain parameter .view

Comment: `viewWillAppear:` is a UIViewController method, not view. It will nevr be called if placed in a UIView subclass

Comment: At interface DrawItemDetails : UIView<UITextViewDelegate>
{
    ItemShow *theItem;
    UISwitch *uiSwitch;
    UIButton *setQualityButton;
}
At property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *uiSwitch;

Comment: So, where's the write place to create UISwitch and draw him up.

Comment: as I said: either in the viewController `-viewDidLoad` or in the view `layoutSubviews`

Comment: This code is how I created my UISwitch. In viewWillAppear I did initialize it. Will it leak?

Comment: yes, as you are creating switches every time viewWillAppear is called.

Comment: (if it would be called. But it won't, as this codes resides in the wrong class)

Comment: see my edit for a possible implementations of UIViews layoutSubviews